# Do we say "do revenge" or "take revenge"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

A title of an American movie is "[do revenge](https://www.google.com/search?q=do%20revenge%20film&oq=do%20revenge%20film&aqs=chrome.0.0i355i512j46i512j0i512l8.4975j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)".

However, most dictionaries say "**take revenge on someone**"

For example, "*He swore to take (his) revenge on his enemies.*"

Do we say "**do revenge**" or "**take revenge**"?

Is "**do revenge**" wrong?

Answer (score 2):

"Do revenge" is a novel expression, not at all idiomatic, bordering on incorrect, invented to make the title of the movie more memorable.

The main characters explain all this in the movie itself at about 27:20:

> Drea: We should team up and do each other's revenge.
> Eleanor: Oh, you're serious. Absolutely not.
> Drea: Why?
> Eleanor: Uh, because I'm not capable? I can't do revenge. I mean, is "Do revenge" even, like, correct grammar?

Comment: I have not watched that film, just came across the tile while on the internet

Comment: Agreed that "do" is very odd paired with revenge, another verb I would say is acceptable (besides "take") is "get", as in "I got my revenge ..."